# DPLL algorithm for 3SAT

Tags: logic, satisfiability

This question is from my complexity theory course.

> How to change the standard DPLL algorithm for SAT in order to solve 3-SAT
>   instances?

The general DPLL algorithm for SAT is defined:

```
Algorithm DPLL
  Input: A set of clauses Φ.
  Output: A Truth Value.
function DPLL(Φ)
   if Φ is a consistent set of literals
       then return true;
   if Φ contains an empty clause
       then return false;
   for every unit clause l in Φ
      Φ ← unit-propagate(l, Φ);
   for every literal l that occurs pure in Φ
      Φ ← pure-literal-assign(l, Φ);
   l ← choose-literal(Φ);
   return DPLL(Φ ∧ l) or DPLL(Φ ∧ not(l));
```

I know that a 3-CNF formula $F$ belongs to 3-SAT if $F$ contains only clauses with 3 literals. But i don't know how to modify DPLL in order to run faster for 3-SAT

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be modified? You can't hope to solve the problem unless you understand what the concepts mean, so maybe start by making sure you know what the problem is.

Comment: I know that a 3-CNF formula $F$ belongs to 3-SAT if $F$ contains only clauses with 3 literals. But i don't know how to modify DPLL in order to run faster for 3-CNF formulas